# spring boot 3 embedded keycloak --proxy=reencrypt

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I have followed a baeldung guide to embed keycloak into a springboot 3 app. I have managed to modify it and use existing postgres database instead of an embedded H2 database by modifying META-INF/keycloak-server.json and I have deployed it with an nginx reverse proxy.

Everything works except for the fact that I need to set proxy=reencrypt for https to be enabled and admin login page to work but I can't find anything in META-INF/keycloak-server.json that would do it nor can I do it from anywhere else.

I have tried everything, googling, scouring keycloak repos and documentations, etc. but I still can't set the proxy option to make it work.